# Calling wlCommonInit() callback from remote page

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've been loading a remote page in Worklight 6.2 using an Android environment:

```
<mainFile>http://example.com/worklight.html</mainFile>
```

Of course the internal `main.js` with the `wlCommonInit()` callback is not called because Worklight can't find the path of the `main.js` javascript file.
So I moved the wlCommonInit() callback into the inline remote HTML source in this way (the following is the remote page `worklight.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>asdapp</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body >
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            Simple text
            <script>
                var wlInitOptions = {};

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('load', function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    window.attachEvent('onload',  function() { WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); });
                }
                function wlCommonInit() {
                    alert("wlCommonInit()");
                }
            </script>           
        </body>
</html>
```

But it's still not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using IBM Portal, the resources of the application must be located on the Portal server in order for the application to find them. You cannot mix & match local and remote resources for the application.

That is, you cannot have a remote index.html that will load jquery.js or main.js or any web resource from the application. They must reside in the same location - on the Portal server per the "using Worklight in Portal" instructions.

Comment: Yes, but in this case I'm testing a non-portal page hosted on my own domain. I supposed the `wlCommonInit()` would be called. Do you have idea why it isn't? (Loading the same page from local works fine)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is Portal or not.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I supposed the callback would be called because it was hardcoded inline in the HTML. My question (which maybe was unclear) is: why it doesn't?

Comment: wlCommonInit is called from worklight.js. A framework file. Your concept will not work.

Comment: If the page is loaded from Worklight internal path it works, else if the page is loaded from an external URL it doesn't work. Frin what I see `worklight.js` calls `wlCommonInit()` and creates an empty `wlCommonInit` if it's not defined, but the function should be defined (inline), even if the page is remote. That's why I don't understand it.

Comment: You're trying to work around the framework in a way that was just not designed for. I don't know why you keep trying to do this. I cannot help you further in this question.